# How to run EpubCheck on Windows?

Tags: epub, windows, epubcheck

How to run EpubCheck on Windows and verify ePub erros without uploading to validator.idpf.org?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a GUI version, that conforms to the standard. It checks all the same places, and the references.

All you would need to do is open the file and drag and drop the EPUB file, you can even verify multiple EPUBs by folder.

The [download page](http://www.pagina-online.de/produkte/epub-checker/) at [pagina](http://www.pagina-online.de) has an English description below the German.
Downloads available for Windows, OSX and Linux.

Comment: If someone prefers not to link directly to the pdf, you can go here: http://www.pagina-online.de/produkte/epub-checker/ . For fellow English speaking folks, Google translates the page fairly well.

Comment: @JasonDown English (for non-German speakers is what I think you meant) was below the German on that page as well. Thanks for pointing out, as I would have missed the availalbility of non-Windows versions of the program.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant @Anthon. Didn't see the English down below.

Answer (score 5):

First go to https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck/releases and download the last version of EpubCheck as zip file. Unzip the folder.

Be sure that you have Java Runtime (1.5 or above) installed, if not go to http://www.java.com to donwload.

Check if the Path variable is set to the folder where java.exe was installed. If not, go to  Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings, tab 'Advanced'. Click on 'Environment Variables...'. Then look for 'Path' on System Variables, click on 'Edit'. To the end of 'Variable Value', add a semicolon and the path to the folder where java.exe was installed.

Put the ePub file in the folder of EpubCheck.

In your console (can be the command prompt cmd), enter `cd [path to the folder unziped of epubcheck]`. Then run `java -jar epubcheck-x.x.x.jar file.epub`, where `x.x.x` is the version of the EpubCheck and `file.epub` is the ePub file.

The console should print the errors and warnings related to your ePub file.

Answer (score 2):

I've too developed a GUI for epubcheck. It's licensed under the GNU AGPLv3 or any later version, written in Java, translated into English and German so far, and it is capable of searching directories recursively for EPUBs. See a [demo video](https://vimeo.com/132641131) and the [source code](https://github.com/publishing-systems/automated_digital_publishing/tree/master/epubcheck). There's also a precompiled download package available.